# Code to set JTable row to different colors not working

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have developed the below listed code which does not work in the fact that it does not set the color of rows to yellow for which the associated timestamp value retrieved from a database table is greater than 1.5 seconds (1500 milliseconds) of the previous row. I will provide only the guts of the code and save you from having to look at all lines such as debug output, logging exceptions, etc.

```
private void processQueryResults(ResultSet results){
    Vector<Vector<String>> resultRows = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    Vector<String> resultRowVector = null;
    Vector<Timestamp> timestampVectors = null;

    resultRows.clear();
    if (results != null){
       timestampVectors = new Vector<Timestamp>();
       While (results.next()){
          resultRowVector = new Vector<String>();
          timestampVectors.add(results.getTimestamp("timestamp_column");

          resultRowVector.add(results.getString("columnA");
          resultRowVector.add(results.getString("columnB");
          .....
          .....
          resultRows.add(resultRowVector);
       }
       JTable displayTable =
             highlightResultRows(new DefaultTableModel(resultRows, colHdrs),
                                 timestampVectors);
       displayTable.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(900,500));
       ......
       ......
    }

    private JTable highlightResultRows(DefaultTableModel model,
                                       final Vector<Timestamp> timestamps){
        Timestamp previousTimestamp = null;
        JTable highlightedTable = new JTable(model){
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
           public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int col){
               Component comp = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
               if (previousTimestamp != null){
                   if (previousTimestamp.getTime() < (timestamps.get(row).getTime() - 1500)){
                       comp.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       comp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                   }
               }
               else
               {
                  comp.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
               }
               previousTimestamp = timestamps.get(row);
               System.out.println("previousTimestamp: [" + previousTimestamp.getTime() + "]");

               return comp;
           }
        };
        return highlightedTable;
    }
```

What I know is not happening is the logic within the prepareRenderer() method is not executing because the debus System.out.println to show what previousTimestamp is set to does not get outputted.  Also all the rows are set to a background color of BLUE.

Comment: *"I will provide only the guts of the code and save you from having to look at all lines"*  For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Andrew I provided what I felt was the minimal required code to help in resolving this issue.  The code provided was want I felt as a software engineer would be needed to possibly provide resolution.  The obvious issue is with method highlghtResultRows which is provided in full as written.  I have provided a subset of the code that generates the input parameters to this method. Not 100% sure what else is needed.

Comment: *"Andrew I provided what I felt was the minimal required code to help in resolving this issue"*  If you can't solve the problem, you are not in a good position to judge whether the relevant code is included.  OTOH I linked to a document that was written by people who have solved lots of problems for newbies, and who know how much easier it can be to help, when runnable code is included.  But hey, it's your problem so approach it as you will.  I'll just vote to close.  Best of luck with it!

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can introduce a method like below and you can pass your `jtable` as the parameter:

```
public void filterRowsWithDifferentColor(JTable table) {

    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            final Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if (!isSelected) {
                try {//assuming the time displaying in your table column 3 with the given format (11:30)  you can change it as you need
                    Time timeValue = new Time(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
                            .parse(table.getValueAt(row, 3).toString()).getTime());

                    long startTime = timeValue.getTime();

                    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    long differenceTime = endTime - startTime;

                    if (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMillis(differenceTime) > 1500) {

                        c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);

                    }
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            return c;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Madushan thanks for the suggested code.  In my case needed to change to compare time values of two consecutive table rows to each other and not against current time.  Works if user scrolls in  forward/downward direction, but I have not found a solution if user scrolls in reverse/upward direction. Unable to determine how to set color of previous processed row's (row n) cells to yellow if time value of current process row (row n-1) is at least 1500 milliseconds earlier.  Previous processed row no longer available to update.  Any additional help would again be appreciated. Thanks, Russell